# Can a sysadmin spy on a Wifi connection?

Tags: network, wifi, web-service

Is it possible that someone who is in charge of a network serving many users, can see what site we visited? I mean, we have only one internet connection, and we used WiFi to be connected. Is it possible that the one who is managing the network can monitor the sites I visited?

Comment: Yes, they probably are able to. Chokepoints and all that. Do they care? Probably not. Depends on if you're at work skiving off and in a jurisdiction that feels the employer paying for the equipment and telecommunications costs is in control of the traffic generated by their employees. If you're at work, you probably need to keep your use to work related content.

Comment: Welcome to Security.Stackexchange! The question title is too vague. Titles are expected to reflect the content. By reading the title, we should have an idea of the question. I took the liberty of choosing a better title (Peer review pending). Also, please check out the short tour: http://security.stackexchange.com/tour
Enjoy SE :)

Answer (score 4):

I assume that you have a network where one system is acting as a router and provides a connection to the internet.

In that case it is possible for the router to monitor all traffic which goes out or enters the network. The administrator of the router could configure it to log the URLs of all websites the users visit. Further, they could log anything they enter into forms. However, when you visit websites via `https`, they only know the domain name of the website you visit, because all other content of the communication is encrypted.